# PHP7's ternary operator ?: return 1 if statement is true

Tags: php

I cannot send correct ajax response because I am using PHP 7. The ternary operator returns 1 in case of true.

Ex:

```
something_true ?: something_else;
```

Will show up 1.

Finally my response looks like:

```
1{status: true}.
```

Number 1 in front of the output is undesired. Please help. I am using php 7.0.8, built on June 21st, 2016.

Comment: Please show us a bit more of the **relevant code** around this ternary operator

Comment: Because you have nothing between the question mark and the colon you are getting a 1 returned if `something_true` is `true`

Comment: What did you want returned if `something_true` was `true`?

Comment: i think that this is the normal behavior of ternary operator !! `Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise. `

Comment: Hi RiggsFolly.

Here is the part of code from Laravel's Vendor there validation's happen: $this->getFromLocalArray($attribute, $lowerRule, $this->fallbackMessages) ?: $key;

So now, when I'm trying: return->response()->json(array('success'=>'true')); code return 1{"status":"error"}, with 1 in front.

Comment: Hi Hassan. Yes, it's the normal behavior. Wrong part it's what php7 shows up 1 (or true), if its true. This is the reason why I cannot send ajax response.

Comment: I get the EXACT same result i.e. `1` for all versions of PHP from 5.3 thru 7.1

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this operator is to provide an easy way to set default values for variables. For example, instead of writing

```
$variable = $inputValue ? $inputValue : 'default-value';
```

You can now write:

```
$variable = $inputValue ?: 'default-value';
```

Which is a little less verbose, but the two are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Motanelu. As a programmer, I know meaning for ternary operator. I just would like to know why php7, not php5, but only php7 shows me up true value. This make some difficults on return ajax response.